# Input rows into Openai API and request fill?

Tags: prompt, openai-api

I have a dataframe with columns containing words (1), their definitions (2), common synonyms (3) and English translation (4). Most of these are filled, however, I was looking for a way to input the words (of incomplete rows) and request corresponding output and fill the table via Open's text engines via API. I have run across a few problems.

So far, I have managed to fill the columns but I get odd returns, such as repeating the request and repeating the input word. This was done using the following code (I have assigned my API key to `api_key`):

```
library(httr)
library(reticulate)

generate_completion <- function(prompt) {
  response <- httr::POST(
    url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/davinci/completions",
    httr::add_headers(`Authorization` = paste("Bearer", api_key)),
    httr::content_type("application/json"),
    body = list(
      prompt = prompt,
      max_tokens = 60,
      temperature = 0.7,
      n = 1
    ),
    encode = "json"
  )
  
  response <- httr::content(response)
  return(response$choices[[1]]$text)
}

# function for filling missing values
fill_missing_values <- function(row) {
  if (is.na(row$Def)) {
    prompt <- paste("What is the definition of", row$Swe, "?")
    row$Def <- generate_completion(prompt)
  }
  
  if (is.na(row$Syn)) {
    prompt <- paste("What are two synonyms for", row$Swe, "?")
    row$Syn <- generate_completion(prompt)
  }
  
  if (is.na(row$Eng)) {
    prompt <- paste("What is the english translation for", row$Swe, "?")
    row$Eng <- generate_completion(prompt)
  }
  
  return(row)
}

#save new values
tab_test1 <- tab_test

# fill missing values with saved values for each row
for (i in 1:nrow(tab_test1)) {
  tab_test1[i, ] <- fill_missing_values(tab_test1[i, ])
}

tab_test1
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you mention the problems you experienced in detail.

Comment: Clarification: The question is about if I am using the right Openai model, and if so, what should I change about the prompts. The specific problem is that the output from the model is not corresponding the prompt. As mentioned above, the answer range from simple repetition of the prompt, to empty numbered lists.

Answer (score 0):

Potential Solutions :

1. Data Preprocessing: Check if any data preprocessing is required before sending the prompts to the API. Make sure that the input data is in the correct format.
2. Error Handling: Implement proper error handling to handle any unexpected responses or errors from the API.

`try-catch` blocks to handle potential exceptions that may occur during API requests or processing of responses. Adding validation checks to ensure that the API response contains the expected data before extracting and using it.

```
library(httr)
library(reticulate)

# Function to handle API request errors
handle_api_errors <- function(response) {
  if (response$status_code != 200) {
    stop(paste("API request failed with status code:", response$status_code))
  }
  if ("error" %in% names(response$content)) {
    stop(paste("API error:", response$content$error$message))
  }
}

# Function to generate completions using the OpenAI API
generate_completion <- function(prompt) {
  tryCatch({
    response <- httr::POST(
      url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/davinci/completions",
      httr::add_headers(`Authorization` = paste("Bearer", api_key)),
      httr::content_type("application/json"),
      body = list(
        prompt = prompt,
        max_tokens = 60,
        temperature = 0.7,
        n = 1
      ),
      encode = "json"
    )
    
    handle_api_errors(response)
    
    response <- httr::content(response)
    return(response$choices[[1]]$text)
  }, error = function(e) {
    # Handle API request errors
    cat("Error:", conditionMessage(e), "\n")
    return(NULL)
  })
}

# Function for filling missing values in the DataFrame
fill_missing_values <- function(row) {
  tryCatch({
    if (is.na(row$Def)) {
      prompt <- paste("What is the definition of", row$Swe, "?")
      row$Def <- generate_completion(prompt)
    }
    
    if (is.na(row$Syn)) {
      prompt <- paste("What are two synonyms for", row$Swe, "?")
      row$Syn <- generate_completion(prompt)
    }
    
    if (is.na(row$Eng)) {
      prompt <- paste("What is the english translation for", row$Swe, "?")
      row$Eng <- generate_completion(prompt)
    }
    
    return(row)
  }, error = function(e) {
    # Handle any other errors that may occur during processing
    cat("Error:", conditionMessage(e), "\n")
    return(NULL)
  })
}

# Save new values
tab_test1 <- tab_test

# Fill missing values with saved values for each row
for (i in 1:nrow(tab_test1)) {
  filled_row <- fill_missing_values(tab_test1[i, ])
  if (!is.null(filled_row)) {
    tab_test1[i, ] <- filled_row
  } else {
    cat("Error: Unable to fill values for row", i, "\n")
  }
}

tab_test1
```

Consider trying other models to see if it works.